# Add XML declaration to XML document programmatically

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-declaration

I want to add the declaration to an XML document generated in Javascript, but I did not find sufficient documentation.

Let's say I want to create programmatically (using Javascript) the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
  <person first-name="eric" last-name="jung" />
</people>
```

Here is the code that I did:

```
let doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
let peopleElem = doc.createElement("people");

let personElem = doc.createElement("person");
personElem.setAttribute("first-name", "eric");
personElem.setAttribute("last-name", "jung");

peopleElem.appendChild(personElem);
doc.appendChild(peopleElem);

let docStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc.documentElement);
console.log(docStr);

// produces:
// <people>
//   <person first-name="eric" last-name="jung" />
// </people>

// and not:
// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
// <people>
//   <person first-name="eric" last-name="jung" />
// </people>
```

How should I do to get the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in the generated XML?

Note: I know that adding a declaration is useless in this case, but eventually I want to use a specific namespace and also add custom XML entities to my document.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't you get an XML serialization with XMLSerializer if you serialize the whole `doc` node and not only its root element/documentElement node? I don't think the DOM API treats the XML declaration as a node, it is something to added during serialization but I am not sure the browser side APIs are very flexible in controlling this.

Comment: As for "custom" entities, the DOM API isn't very flexible and powerful for that either, but `createDocument` used to allow to pass in a DTD/doctype parameter.

Comment: It seems even serializing the whole document doesn't output an XML declaration, mainly because `serializeToString` is not needing one. Not sure whether any more lower-level APIs to serialize to a stream or file exists where the ability to set/ensure a particular encoding would be needed.

Comment: Would you suggest using a library such as [this one](https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js) to solve my problems? (adding declaration, adding custom entities, ...)

Comment: Apparently it is still possible to [add a CDATA tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createCDATASection) programmatically for my XML entities. However, I still have some issues: I also need to include a `<?xml-model ...?>` tag at the beginning of my XML document. Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: That is a processing instruction the DOM (core/XML) API should support, unless the HTML5 guys/DOM4 guys have crippled browser APIs to no longer support them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

See the [list of compatible node types for XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString#compatible_node_types).

There is [ProcessingInstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProcessingInstruction) node that can be created with [createProcessingInstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createProcessingInstruction) method.

Finally, you need to serialize the whole document, not only the `documentElement`.

```js
const doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
const peopleElem = doc.createElement("people");

const pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction('xml', 'version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"');
doc.insertBefore(pi, doc.firstChild);

const personElem = doc.createElement("person");

personElem.setAttribute("first-name", "eric");
personElem.setAttribute("last-name", "jung");

peopleElem.appendChild(personElem);

doc.appendChild(peopleElem);

const docStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);

console.log(docStr);
```